# Groupby at index level in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following MultiIndex DataFrame and I'm wondering if there is a way to apply different functions on the second level index.

```
import pandas as pd
# Creation
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,1],[4,5,1],[4,5,2]], columns=["M1","M2","month"])
df1['var']="v1"
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1.5,2.5,1],[4.5,5.5,1],[1.5,1.5,2]], columns=["M1","M2","month"])
df2['var']="v2"
df_all = pd.concat([df1,df2],join='outer')

# Final DataFrame
df_all_idx = df_all.set_index(["month","var"],inplace=False)
df_all_idx.sort_index(level=[0])

                M1  M2
month    var        
1        v1     1.0 2.0
         v1     4.0 5.0
         v2     1.5 2.5
         v2     4.5 5.5
2        v1     4.0 5.0
         v2     1.5 1.5
```

With groupby I can obtain:

```
df_grp = df_all_idx.groupby(by=["month","var"]).sum()

                M1  M2
month   var     
1       v1      5.0 7.0
        v2      6.0 8.0
2       v1      4.0 5.0
        v2      1.5 1.5
```

For example, I would need to apply sum() to v1 values and a custom function to v2 values.

Thanks

Comment: split the dataframe , apply the function you need then concat back

Comment: @Wen strictly speaking, you don't *need* to split it.

Comment: maybe i would (1) unstack the second level so they become columns, (2) group by the remaining level, and then (3) apply different aggregations to `v1` and `v2` with `agg(func={"v1": func1, "v2": func2})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like dictionaries. So I would store your aggregating functions in a dictionary, and look them up based on each group's name.

```
import numpy
import pandas

aggregators = {
    'v2': numpy.min
}


df1 = pandas.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2, 1],[4, 5, 1],[4, 5, 2]],
    columns=["M1", "M2", "month"]
).assign(var='v1')

df2 = pandas.DataFrame(
    [[1.5,2.5,1], [4.5,5.5,1], [1.5,1.5,2]],
    columns=["M1", "M2", "month"]
).assign(var='v2')

df = (
    pandas.concat([df1, df2], join='outer')
        .groupby(by=['month', 'var'])
        .apply(lambda g: aggregators.get(g.name[-1], numpy.sum)(g))
        [['M1', 'M2']]
)
```

And that's:

```
            M1   M2
month var          
1     v1   5.0  7.0
      v2   1.5  2.5
2     v1   4.0  5.0
      v2   1.5  1.5
```

This line: `.apply(lambda g: aggregators.get(g.name[-1], numpy.sum)(g))` is a little complicated. Here's what it does:

1. `.apply` loops through all of the groups and runs them through the lambda
2. Each group has a `name` attribute that is the values of grouping columns
3. `g.name[-1]` is the last element (v1, v2)
4. `aggregators.get(g.name[-1], numpy.sum)` looks up the function to use, but if a function can't be found, it defaults to `numpy.sum`
5. then we pass the group to the function that we looked up

Comment: @ScottBoston if i can avoid thinking through `if/elif/else` logic with a dictionary, i go with the dictionary 95% of the time

Comment: @PaulH using a dict is clever

Comment: One thing can improve `pandas.concat([df1, df2], join='outer',keys=['v1','v2']) ` and you do not need assign

Comment: @Wen that's a tangential detail related to creating the reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
df_all_idx.xs('v1', level=1).sum(axis=1)
df_all_idx.xs('v2', level=1).apply(some_function, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion to split, apply and concat back I came up with this solution:

```
def myfunc(x):
    return np.mean(x)

p1 = df_all_idx.loc[(slice(None), 'v1'), :].groupby(by=["month","var"]).sum()    
p2 = df_all_idx.loc[(slice(None), 'v2'), :].groupby(by=["month","var"]).agg(myfunc)

pd.concat([p1,p2], join='outer').sort_index(level=[0])
```

That return the result as I want it:

```
                 M1     M2
 month  var     
 1       v1      5.0    7.0
         v2      3.0    4.0
 2       v1      4.0    5.0
         v2      1.5    1.5
```

I assume then that this is the best practice in this case.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to slice and perform the aggregations separately requiring you to concat at the end.